# How come register file size in GPU's (eg GTX 1080) bigger than L2 cache size?

Tags: memory-management, gpu, cpu-registers, cpu-cache

Looking at this fact, I've started wondering how registers work in GPU? Before knowing this, I thought going higher and higher above the hierarchical memory ladder, the size keeps on decreasing (which is intuitive (latency decrease, size decrease)). What is the purpose of registers in GPU's and why is their size greater than the L2/L1 cache?
Thanks.

Comment: GPUs are said to have 'inverted memory hierarchy', because GPUs seek to optimize throughput and not latency. To keep their latency small, GPU RF uses operand collector and multiple banks. See my [survey paper on GPU register file](https://www.academia.edu/23514653/A_Survey_of_Techniques_for_Architecting_and_Managing_GPU_Register_File) for more details on GPU RF architecture, management techniques and (RF, L1 and L2)-size trends in recent GPUs.

Answer (score 7):

In CPUs caches serve two basic purposes:

1. They enable temporal and spatial reuse of data already fetched from DRAM. This reduces the required bandwidth of the DRAM.
2. CPU caches provide a huge reduction of latency, which is extremely important for single threaded performance.

GPUs are not focused on single thread performance, but are focused on throughput instead. Most of the time they also deal with working sets that are too big to fit into any reasonably sized cache. Small cache help in some situation, but overall caches are not nearly as important for GPUs as they are for CPUs.

Now to the second part of the question: Why huge registers files? GPUs reach their performance by exploiting thread level parallelism. Many threads need to be active at the same time to reach high performance levels. But every thread needs to store its own set of registers. In Maxwell GPUs and likely in GP104/GTX1080 every SM can host up to 2048 threads. Every SM has a 256 KB register file, so if all threads are used, 32x 32-bit registers are available per thread.

I mentioned earlier that CPUs use caches to reduce memory latency, but GPUs must also somehow deal with memory latency. They just switch to a different thread, while a thread is waiting for an answer from the memory. Latency and throughput and threads are connected by Little's law:

(data in flight/thread) * threads = latency x throughput

The memory latency is likely a few hundred ns to thousand ns (lets use 1000ns). The throughput here would be the memory bandwidth (320 GB/s). To full utilize the available memory bandwidth we need at (320 GB/s * 1000 ns=) 320 KB in flight. GTX1080 should have 20 SMs, so each SM would need to have 16 KB in flight to full use the memory bandwidth. Even if all 2048 threads are used for memory access all the time, every thread would still be required to have 8 bytes in outstanding memory requests. If some threads are busy with calculations and cannot send out new memory requests, even more memory requests are required from the remaining threads. If threads use more than 32 registers per thread, even more memory requests per thread are needed.

If GPUs would use smaller register files, they could not use the full bandwidth of their memory. They would send out some work to memory interface and then all threads would be waiting for answers from the memory interface and no new work could be submitted to the memory interface. The huge registers are required to have enough threads available. Careful coding is still required to really get the maximum power of the GPU.

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate the statement "If some threads are busy with calculations and cannot send out new memory requests, even more memory requests are required from the remaining threads" 2. I understand that this large register size is important for switching between threads, but in the end, those registers are fed by L2 cache, so in the event of all threads requiring memory access, L2 cache will become the bottleneck. How do you explain this?

Comment: 1. That simple little's law model assumes that all threads will send out new memory requests as soon as the answer to their last request from the memory interface is received. But for actual GPU applications the threads will first do some calculation on the received values. The duration of these calculation can even vary, because of this only a subset of threads is available for hiding the memory latency. Even with the high number of threads supported by today's GPUs clever programming is often required to avoid performance degradation by too low occupancy.

Comment: 2. Many threads will make requests to the L2 cache, the L2 cache needs to have a high throughput to handle all these concurrent requests. But a high throughput cache does not have to be big in memory size. For current GPU applications a significantly larger L2 cache would not provide a huge improvement in hit rates. L2 would only be a bottleneck if the throughput of the L2 is too low. A typical CPU L2 cache would be likely be a real bottleneck in GPU: While its bigger size would provide only slightly better hit rates, it could not deal with the high number of concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

GPU is built for 3D and calculations so vendors dedicated more area for cores. More cores need more data to feed them and that needs more gpu area for scheduling mechanisms to maintain occupation as high as possible.

Too many cores, too many 3D pipelines such as **tmu** and **rop**, too many scheduling parts and too wide **memory controllers** to feed those cores.

Gpu area is just not enough for everything. Least important one seems to be caches. Even **texture memory** is more important than that and that is faster too.

Making gpu bigger means lower yield for production and that means less profit. Since gpu vendors are not charity organisations, they chose maximum profit, optimum performance and power savings(as of lately). **Cache is expensive**.

A compute unit in a gpu can have **more than kilobytes of registers per thread** so any multiply used data is not needed to be transferred between long distances(such as cache and cores) and make it have **energy efficieny**.

Also you can hide latency of some parts by having good occupation ratio for large-enough calculations; **local shared memory**(per compute unit) and registers(per thread) has more important role in achieving that.

While memory controller,L1 and L2 can handle only 100 GB/s, 200 GB/s and 300 GB/s;local shared memory and **registers** can be up to 5 TB/s and **15 TB/s bandwidth** for a gpu.